# Error of first installation ubuntu 16.04.3 on ASUS TUF X299 MARK 2 ATX LGA2066 Motherboard

Tags: graphics, asus, acpi, m2

Could you please give me an idea how I should tackle the problem ([error message in details](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4el8m47xvcqppaq/File%2007-09-2017%2C%2011%2016%2027%20AM.jpeg?dl=0))? I have looked up for the solution and followed the suggestion to update the Bios to the latest version ([Asus 0702](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/TUF-X299-MARK-2/HelpDesk_BIOS/)). The error retains.

```
Error:  
ACPI Error: [SDS0] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)  
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed, [\SHAD._STA] (Node ffff...), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)  
ACPI Error: [SDS0] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)
```

Info:

- Motherboard: ASUS - TUF X299 MARK 2 ATX LGA2066 Motherboard
- CPU: Intel - Core i7-7800X 3.5GHz 6-Core Processor
- Memory: G.Skill - Ripjaws V Series 32GB (2 x 16GB) DDR4-3200 Memory
- Storage: Samsung - 960 EVO 250GB M.2-2280 Solid State Drive
- Video Card: MSI - GeForce GTX 1080 Ti 11GB DUKE OC Video Card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot option `acpi=off` for installation and kernel update for the system help with that error. But does your system hang in few seconds after successful launch?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. No it didn't hang in at all. I got the error message right after reboot. Since my friend and I were intensively trying to make it work couple days ago, we decided to install mint and it runs with CPU for now. We don't have a chance to test GPU yet. We might switch back to ubuntu once we have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: It stopped to hang after update. But I have to use `acpi=off` again after update!

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the tip and I will try whether this works while we switch back to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case.
I am having 2 Flash drives with:

Most recent one ISO.

One year old Ubuntu ISO

After purchasing Asus TUF X299 Mark 2 I was having bios 0503.

Most recent Ununtu failed to boot from Flash (I did not try acpi=off setting)

My old Ubuntu ISO was working fine and I got Ubuntu installed up and running.

Then i upgraded bios to most recent one: 0802.

And then my Ubuntu stopped booting with the same exact error message.
The acpi=off trick was working for me but I have noticed some weird behaviour with my keyboard (along with halved cores).

After downgrading bios to 0503 my Ubuntu again was working fine for me again.

So check your bios and try downgrading it. Maybe it will help.