# X299 ACPI Error: UEFI or Driver/Kernel bug?

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, uefi, intel

I purchased a new machine with an i7-7820X, a MSI X299 Raider and 64 GB of memory. Unfortunately I have problems booting the machine. It ends in emergency mode with the following error messages:

```
kernel: Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
kernel: ACPI Error: [SDS0] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)
kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\SHAD._STA] (Node ffff8f559e548050), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
```

After some research I found 2 other people with similar hardware and the same problem [here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/117521) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953648/error-of-first-installation-ubuntu-16-04-3-on-asus-tuf-x299-mark-2-atx-lga2066-m). They have a board from Asus.

I tried different kernel version up to 4.12 (Ubuntu 17.10, 17.04, Fedora 26) and different Firmware version for my Motherboard (including Beta versions).   Nothing helped all gave the same error.
At the moment I can boot and use my system with the `acpi=off` boot option, but this disables Hyperthreading.

So my question is now, is this a bug related to the kernel or to the firmware?
If the kernel is the problem, which version would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a new Beta-Bios yesterday (1.42). This solves the problem.
I can now boot a standard Ubuntu 17.04 normally and with ACPI turned on.
So far it also looks stable.

Comment: I updated `MSI X299 SLI` BIOS to version 1.50 (also tried 1.61 beta) and then saved GRUB configuration. After that I can't boot anymore - with or without `acpi=off` parameter, using kernel 19, 33 and 35. Nothing works anymore :(

Comment: I used the system for some time and it was stable. Then with the uptdate to the 35 Kernel I had to turn acpi off again. With the kernel update some other packages where updated. I think one of them is the reason for the problem now, because the system does also not boot with the 33 Kernel. Unfortunatly I had no time to go through the packages, yet. Concerning your boot problem, did you also add `intel_pstate=disable` to the boot options?

Comment: `intel_pstate=disable` has no effect for me. I updated system again and now it works with 33 kernel and `acpi=off` option.

Comment: WIth the new 37 Kernel it is stable since a few days with `acpi=on`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such errors with the latest available kernel. I updated it and the errors gone. You should skip system update for that - update only kernel! But Ubuntu works only few seconds (with NVidia graphics card driver) or several minutes (without it) until it hangs and reboots.

If you update the whole system then you should remain `acpi=off` boot option because of another issue...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the latest mainline kernel (4.13.1) but I get the same error and it crashes as you mentioned.

Comment: I use kernel 4.10.33 (the latest available using apt-get).

Comment: That is what I am also using now, it is stable with acpi=off and nvidia-385 drivers. When I turn acpi on I get the Error stated in the question.