# Ubuntu Asus Prime x299-A

Tags: boot, drivers, uefi, bios, acpi

I've seen some posts out there about difficulties getting Ubuntu running on the x299 platform due to ACPI issues with some users reporting success with certain motherboards and bios versions.

I have a core i9 7980XE with an Asus Prime x299-A motherboard and have tried to get Ubuntu 17.10.1 running but keep running into the same ACPI issue like the one here: [X299 ACPI Error: UEFI or Driver/Kernel bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955251/x299-acpi-error-uefi-or-driver-kernel-bug)

I've tried to use every bios version available with this board but I can only boot into the live version/installer with ACPI=off which disables hyperthreading. Has anyone had any success getting Ubuntu working with this board and if so, what bios version and ubuntu/kernel version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

My computer comes preinstalled with Windows 10. I updated the BIOS to 1.70 and all the ACPI errors disappeared.

I made the following changes in the BIOS:

- Boot Mode = UEFI
- Disabled Fast Boot
- Disabled Secure Boot (It comes disabled by default.)
- Disabled Turbo Boost
- Legacy USB Support = Auto (With Disabled it just goes directly to BIOS.)
- Disabled UEFI hard disk drive for Windows Manager (Since I have two hard drives, I decided to disconnect the SATA cable for the Windows hard drive so that it does not interfere in the installation.)

This solution works for Ubuntu 17.10, not for 16.04 unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got things working by installing 16.04.2. Was never able to install anything newer. Am using bios 1301, dual booting windows 10 and Ubuntu from M.2 SSD. Did not need to set any flags to boot Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar troubles with an i9-7940X + ASUS Prime X299-A combination. When I first turned it on it would spontaneously reboot every few minutes, which made Ubuntu 17.10 installation challenging.

I then upgraded the BIOS version from 0702 (08/08/2017) to 1301 (03/07/2018). That improved things to the point where it would spontaneously reboot only every couple of hours.

I then tried a few more things:

- Using `acpi=off` to disable Hyperthreading fixed the problem, but it cost me 15% performance on my workload of interest.
- Using `acpi=ht` with TurboBoost also fixed the problem, but that caused a similar slowdown.
- With `acpi=ht` and TurboBoost on the problem continued.

I eventually got a replacement motherboard, a Gigabyte X299 Aorus Gaming 9. When I first turned it on, I again got a couple of spontaneous reboots after about 2 hours. But then I updated its BIOS version from F5 to F8c and since then it's been completely stable for several days.