# Boot and random freeze problems with 18.04 on ASUS X299 Prime Deluxe

Tags: boot, nvidia, freeze, nvidia-geforce

From last one month, I have been struggling to 
make Ubuntu 18.04 work on my newly assembled system with ASUS X299 Prime Deluxe 
motherboard and NVIDIA 1080Ti, SAMSUNG 970 EVO NVMe disk.

Has anyone tried this configuration ?

One noticable symptoom is that every day when I start the system, I get few call traces quickly after the grub menu, and after 2-3 hard reboots, the system will boot up login screen. After that throughout the day I don't see those call traces, but i start seeing random freezes after 5-15 mins of login from login screen.

I can't do anything (like going to console `Ctrl-Alt-F2` etc) during the freeze which is annoying. If I were able to go to the console at least i could have debugged it a little further.

I tried `intel_idle.max_cstate=1, nouveau.modeset=0, acpi=off, nomodeset,` in various permutations and combinations, but nothing seems to work.

Call trace 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEV8m.jpg
Call trace 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYrxx.jpg
Call trace 3 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NqwP.jpg

I also saw this https://askubuntu.com/a/1025233/884359. Is this known problem with 18.04,if yes what is causing this problem ?

CPU temperature is bellow 45 deg. C and Power Supply is 1000W and the UPS connected to system shows Power usage below 200W always

Ubuntu is booted up with Legacy BIOS (UEFI BIOS and secure boot is disabled)

Comment: I think you would be much better describing the "struggle" and asking for solutions for a specific problem then asking about personal experiences. I may help you with the specific problem but if you ask me if I tried that configuration the answer will be "no, I haven't and probably never will".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Major issue is of the freeze one, I am not even able to try Ctrl-Alt-F2 to go to console to see why the freeze, everything is just stuck, I can't do anything except keep the power button pressed and force the system to shutdown. I have few images of call traces during boot, but I can't post the images until I have reputation of 10 it seems !

Comment: Please [edit] the question. Regarding your problem, it has a name: Nvidia graphics. Use `nomodeset` to install and until you install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia You mean, while installing I need to set `nomodeset` and after the installation is over I need to install NVIDIA drivers ? How do I supply this kernel cmdline argument during installation, where is this option to supply that argument ?

Comment: in the first menu that appears select and edit "Try Ubuntu". Add `nomodeset`to the line with "quiet splash".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Let me try this immediately and get back .. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  UPDATE :: Installed the system with `nomodeset` option, once the system boots up and I login into the system after say 10 mins, system hung again .. I have not even downloaded the NVIDIA drivers ...

Comment: That why above I said *to install and until you install Nvidia drivers*. Meaning: `nomopdeset` is required to avoid such hanging/freezes if it doesn't have the drivers installed yet. I think you need to press shift while booting to get the Grub menu to edit again. And do not download from. The additional drivers tools is meant for that.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I did all that install as per your suggestion `NVIDIA-SMI 410.66` and kernel `4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu`, but still I am getting random freeze. How to find out reason for these freezes ?

Comment: Too many possibilities now. Some problem in Ubuntu can't be ruled how but hardware is more probable. Perhaps the power supply isn't enough for the graphics card, etc.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Power supply is 1000W, what else CPU temp ? Besides, I am not even running any load on the system...

Comment: I'm no expert. I assemble a desktop and/or replace parts in a desktop or laptop but that's all. Such freezes are hard to troubleshoot and I'm assuming the OS Ubuntu was correctly installed in UEFI mode - the NVMe SSD wouldn't probably be detected in Legacy - as well as the Nvidia drivers... At this point I would start checking the hardware but I would have no idea where to start, sorry.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia in UEFI mode there are lots of installation issues so Ubuntu is booted up `without secure boot` with legacy BIOS. What do you mean by "correctly installed in UEFI mode" any pointers please. Please don't be sorry, appreciate your help in difficult times.

Comment: THere's your problem. **No, there are no issues with Ubuntu in UEFI.** There are some *laptops* with "weird" UEFI implementations and some workarounds or additional steps are required, that's all. Running such new hardware in Legacy is ridiculous!! Probably it's **the** cause of freezes and underperforming (please note the "probably").

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Can you please give me some examples of _what kind of some workarounds or additional steps are required ?_ it will give me at least some direction or idea ...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/tour to understand this isn't a forum. It's a Q&A site where you can post an answerable specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You're having kernel panics. Somewhat difficult to diagnose, so lets try the basics first. `fsck` and `memtest`.

## Step #1

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

## Step #2

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run `memtest` for at least one complete pass.

Report back.

Comment: These panics happen only when I power on the machine after the machine is shut off completely (without power). Yeah, this is strange, but this is my observation. Once the machine boots up after few initial  hard reboots, then there is no problem, systems boots up without any issues. I am not sure why this is not happening ...

Comment: @OnkarNMahajan you didn't say whether you did my suggestions or not.